# Shell: How to increment first occuring integer in a variable

Tags: shell, awk

I have

```
$string1=\-9-0  ---> $increment1=\-10-0
$string2=\-99   ----> $increment2=\-100
$string3=\-999-0-4 --> $increment3=\-1000-0-4
```

I need to just increment the first occurring integer to +1 value and integers are prefixed with `-`

Comment: why is string changed to increment? and you should also post what you tried to solve this...

Comment: Just tried to differentiate how the incremented string will look like for an example. i didn't solve it looking  for help  to get   that solution

Comment: you need to better format the question, put input and output into two separate code blocks... change only things you need to be changed... and this forum is about getting help on code you tried but didn't work.. not about getting entire code ...

Comment: @sundeep my question is straight to the point  anyway thanks for trying

Comment: if it is straight forward as you say, why then did you change `string` to `increment`? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681943/how-to-remove-all-alphabets-numbers-and-from-a-file-in-bash for an example of better way of asking - it shows sample input/output separately and more importantly, OP adds code already tried

Comment: and reading your comments on answers, seems like your input data is `\-9-0` and not `$string1=\-9-0`... that is not clear at all from your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} {$2=$2+1; print}' <<<$string1
```

Explanation :

We've set Field Separator/ delimiter i.e `FS` as `-` , 
therefore in string `-9-0` the second field would be `9`.
We are then incrementing `$2` by `1`.  Also `OFS=-` so that when fields are printed `-` is included as delimiter otherwise awk considers space  as the delimiter by default.

To store it back to variable :

```
$ string1=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} {$2=$2+1;}1' <<<$string1)

$ echo $string1
-10-0


$ string3=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} {$2=$2+1;}1' <<<$string3)

$ echo $string3
-1000-0-4
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks BATMAN for the rescue :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

**One-liner:**

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}match($2,/[0-9]+/){sub(/[0-9]+/,substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)+1,$2)}1' infile
```

OR even this will work for given input sample

```
awk -F'[^[:digit:]]+' '{t=$0; sub(/-[0-9]+/,"-"$3+1,t); print t }' infile
```

**Input:**

```
$ cat infile
$string1=\-9-0  
$string2=\-99   
$string3=\-999-0-4
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}match($2,/[0-9]+/){sub(/[0-9]+/,substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)+1,$2)}1' infile
$string1=\-10-0  
$string2=\-100   
$string3=\-1000-0-4 

$ awk -F'[^[:digit:]]+' '{t=$0; sub(/-[0-9]+/,"-"$3+1,t); print t }' infile
$string1=\-10-0  
$string2=\-100   
$string3=\-1000-0-4
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk  '
      BEGIN{
             FS=OFS="="
      }
      match($2,/[0-9]+/){
            sub(/[0-9]+/,substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)+1,$2)
      }1
     ' infile
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the help.  Can we do the same thing instead of file input. Can we do echo  "\-9" | awk .....  should give me \-10.