# How to remove all alphabets, numbers '@' and '.' from a file in bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a data of email id's and i want to check if email id's contain any special character other than '@' and '.' so i want to remove all the alphabets, numbers, '@' and '.'. I know to remove all digits we can use following command:

```
sed 's/[0-9]*//g' input.txt > output.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
aurora-oval@galaxy.plala.or.jp                                                  
xia1356shishiwen@163.com                                                        
hira#no@maruwadengyo.co.jp                                                       
shop@lov$echarms.jp                                                              
n.yamaguchi-arc.s@vega.ocn.ne.jp
```

Sample Output:

```
-

#
$
-
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Maybe [Removing special characters in file](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/24065-removing-special-characters-file.html) could help you

Comment: I want to check what special characters are present there, how could be removing them help me

Comment: Please don't vandalize questions by removing information after they have been answered. If you need to redact information, flag for moderator attention, otherwise it will remain in the revision history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with tr:

```
tr -d '[[:alnum:]].@' <filename
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked,  what if i want to remove all '-' and '+' as well?

Comment: just add in quotes `'[[:alnum:]].@+-'`